# How can i add a new link to the ECB(Context Menu) sharepoint 2013 list item

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, settings

What would be the easiest way to add a custom link to the context item menu?
   Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Add a `CustomAction` and specify `Location="EditControlBlock"`. Example:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="SomeID"
    RegistrationType="List"
    RegistrationId="101"
    ImageUrl="/_layouts/1033/Images/SOMEIMAGE.GIF"
    Location="EditControlBlock"
    Sequence="301"
    Title="My Custom ECB Menu Item" >
      <UrlAction
        Url="~site/somepage.aspx?ItemId={ItemId}&amp;ListId={ListId}"/>        
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```