# Cannot share list item in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, custom-list

I'm very new to SharePoint and trying SP2013.

I'm able to share a document in Document library using the ellipses ... from the UI. However I expected the same with list items which is not available. (neither in the ribbon nor in the ellipses menu).

Please let me know is this a limitation on SharePoint or an issue with permissions?

Comment: You want to share whole document library?

Comment: No. I want to share only a selected list item.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Online, you can manage permissions for a list item by clicking the ellipses, then "Advanced settings" and then "manage permissions". "Manage permissions" is the same as "Share".

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not built in, but you could add such a UI-Menu Point via Code.
Like mentioned here:
[How can i add a new link to the ECB(Context Menu) sharepoint 2013 list item](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98391/how-can-i-add-a-new-link-to-the-ecbcontext-menu-sharepoint-2013-list-item)

Comment: Can we at least give edit permissions on a list item to a particular user/group through web services?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/manage-permissions-for-a-list-library-folder-document-or-list-item-HA010021564.aspx#BM8