# Share with is disabled on ribbon for custom list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, 2016, share

What is condition for disabling/enabling "Share With" button on ribbon for lists/libraries?

When I create custom list and select any item, the button is grayed out.
[image]

When I create document library and select any item, button is enabled and it works correctly.
[image]

So it means that for lists it's not working, but there is MicroFeed list and when I select any item the "Share with" is enabled and working in the same way as in Document Library.
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this functionality not available in the classic sites. If you have the SharePoint online site you can share the list items with others or if you have modern team site in SharePoint 2019 then you can share a list item with others. 
I performed the test in various farm and here are the results:

- In SharePoint 2019 (Classic SharePoint): when i click on list item and in ribbon i can see Shared With option.[image]
- In SharePoint 2019 (Modern SharePoint): [image]

  - In SharePoint 2016, no sharing for list items but for list.
  - IN SPO, you can share the list item same way as SharePoint 2019:[image]

Please read the following post to understand it: [Share a list item in SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-a-list-item-in-sharepoint-online-c270ccaf-89a2-4f7e-874a-5da98824d449)

and [How to enable Item Level Permissions in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-enable-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thanks for your time spent on investigation. This is a little bit confusing to be honest. So for custom list on SP2016 there is no way to get "Shared With" enabled on ribbon? I've checked on SP2013 and it is enabled, you sent screenshot on SP2019 it is enabled too. So it's SP2016 issue?

Comment: are you sure it is available for SharePoint 2013? Item level sharing what i believe not available for list item level.

Comment: check this question, he is talking sp 2013: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103305/cannot-share-list-item-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Yes it is enabled but it only shows list of accounts and "Advanced" link.